# "Be from ..." vs. "Come from ..."

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "He comes from the U.S." and "He is from the U.S."?  Can you always use them interchangeably, or is there a subtle difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, they both should be interchangeable. As a native speaker, "He **comes from** the U.S." sounds to me like it could mean "he **was formerly in** the U.S.", whereas "He **is from** the U.S." sounds more common and does not carry that ambiguity.